# Matching the year "2XXX" in a CSV file

Tags: java, regex, csv

The following is a sample line from a CSV file I'm trying to parse using regex or `string.split(",")`, and I want to extract the year (in below example, 2013). But the problem is: the year column index is not always 17, it could also be 19. I am thinking of looping through the each string in the `string.split(",")` array and match the pattern against `"2XXX"`.

> 9344949,HW488429,10/09/2013 05:00:00 AM,039XX W MONROE
>      ST,0610,BURGLARY,FORCIBLE
>      ENTRY,RESIDENCE,false,false,1122,011,28,26,05,1149955,1899326,**2013**,10/16/2013
>      12:39:00 AM,41.87966141386545,-87.72485045045373,"(41.87966141386545,
>      -87.72485045045373)"

This can break down each line in the CSV file

```
Pattern.compile("^([^,]+,){2}\\d{2}/\\d{2}/(\\d{4})([^,]+,){3}([^,]+)");
```

But I need some help matching each string against `2XXX`. Tried this:
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("^2\d{3}"); however, my eclipse reports error on this.

Comment: Please try reducing the problem - I think it'll be hard for people to mentally parse all that you have written here.

Comment: I would use a real CSV parser. There might be escaped delimiters. Quotes. Escaped quotes. All sorts of strange things that CSV parsers can handle and that your code cannot. While this is doable with regex it won't be pretty so I would recommend avoiding it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I strongly advise you try using a CSV parser like Boris suggested.

IF you must do it your way you could do something like

```
String year;
String str = // your csv line
String[] strArr = str.split(",");
for(String s : strArr)
{
    if(s.trim().matches("2\\d{3}"))
    {
        year = s;
        break;
    }
}
```